# Mathtext markers in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

As I need to plot many curves in a single figure, I need many different types of markers. Sometimes the number of the default markers are not enough, so it would be nice if the user could customize the marker types.

According to the document page (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_marker), it is possible to use mathtext as the marker. However, it did not work in my case.

`plot(x, y, marker='$||$')  # To use two vertical lines as the marker.`

The error message is like this:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3432, in plot
  for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 311, in _grab_next_args
  for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 298, in _plot_args
  seg = func(x[:,j%ncx], y[:,j%ncy], kw, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 248, in _makeline
  self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 191, in set_lineprops
  func(val)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/lines.py", line 804, in set_marker
  self._markerFunc = self._markers[marker]
KeyError: '$||$'
```

The matplotlib version is:

```
matplotlib.__version__
'0.99.1.1'
```

I also tried `plot(x, y, marker=r'$||$')`, which does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set `text.usetex` in your matplotrc file? You also need to use the right output backend, such as Postscript or PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the following but the result is the same:
    matplotlib.use('cairo.ps')        
    matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)

Comment: Hm. That's strange. Could you try using mathtext somewhere else? For instance add a label to the plot, see if it renders correctly

Comment: I tried something like the following for the mathtext and it seems to be quite fine: add_subplot(1,1,1, xscale='log', yscale='log', xlim=(1,100), ylim=(1,10), xlabel=r'$n_{{\rm H}}$', ylabel=r'$\frac{1}{2}$', title='$\mu$m,$_H$ = 10 cm$^{{-3}}$'
So I think there is no problem with the normal mathtext.

Comment: Now that I'm home, I could try it out myself. However, for me it works without any problems... I have matplotlib 1.0.1, is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Then I guess it might be related with the version. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade it.

Comment: @user789977 - It should work regardless of whether you're using actual `tex` (which is what the `usetex` option sets) or matplotlib's built-in mathtext renderer, which is what is used by default. Setting the `text.usetex` option shouldn't have any effect. However, it looks like using mathtext for markers was added at the end of 2009, which is after the `0.99.1` release, as you've already found out.

Comment: @Joe Kington Thanks for you comment! I will try to ask the administrator to upgrade the package.